# how can i set value from dropdown list on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

i am beginner on rails. I have product - brands list.

routes rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :brands do
    resources :products
  end
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Brand.rb

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

products.controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_brand
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def new
    if params[:brand_id]
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    end
    @product = Product.new

  end

  def edit
    @brand = @product.brand
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def create
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.create(product_params)
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def destroy
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def update
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
  end

  helper_method :update

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name)
    end

    def set_brand
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    end

end
```

.../products/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add a new product</h1>
<%= form_with(model: [ @brand, @brand.products.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name,"Product name: " %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>

  </p>
  <%= form.label :title,"Select a Brand" %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :title,{selected: @brand.id}) %>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit "Add a product" %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

[new.html.erb picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6p65.png)

so i want to set brand_id from selected item on dropdown list. This case, i select first item for brand_id but i cant change the brand_id. How can i set brand_id which is selected from dropdown list ? and how can i save it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have setup products as a nested resource you neither need or want that select. The brand_id param will be passed through the path (the action attribute of the form). The user would choose what brand he wants to add a product to by what link he clicked to get to the new form.

While you could add a select to the form its a major WTF moment when you send:

```
POST /brands/1/products, { products: { brand_id: 5 }}
```

And it ends up creating a product that does not belong to Brand 1. If the param from the form was blank you would also get a really strange result.

If really wanted a form where the user selects the "target" brand on the form itself you would create a non-nested respresentation:

```
<%= form_with(model: @product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :brand_id %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # POST /products
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
       redirect_to @product
    else
       render :new
    end
  end

  def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:foo, :bar, :brand_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: why i cant save them ? i used your codes. when i clicked the button, it cant be saved.

Comment: Because a validation might be failing? I bet you can troubleshoot this on your own. The problem with your original code is that you're not actually checking if the record is saved/updated. You're just assuming it will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to permit the parameter in `product_params`. Which should be:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :brand_id)
```

Unpermitted parameters are ignored by the `create` and `update` methods.